# Traversing the DOM with load() method

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, the `.load()` method allows you to import the specific content, for example, of a certain `id` using selectors:

```
$("#div1").load("demo_test.txt #p1");
```

With jQuery (and if possible without functions but just using selectors), how do I select, for example, the previous element to that `id`?

Eg 1 (mistaken):

```
$("#div1").load("demo_test.txt #p1").prev();
```

Eg 2 (mistaken):

```
$("#div1").load("demo_test.txt #p1.prev()");
```

Comment: `$.get("demo_test.txt",function(res){ $("#div1").html($(res).find('#p').prev()); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with [`load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) method instead of that use [`jQuery.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and get the element from the response.

```
$.get("demo_test.txt",function(res){ 
  $("#div1").html($(res).find('#p').prev()); 
},'html')
```

Comment: **EDIT**: sorry, excuse me, I have found the answer, I did not want to bother you over :-)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875528/jquery-post-vs-get
___
Many thanks: it works very well.
In case I have to use a selector (without traversing the DOM), the `.get()` method is better/faster than the `.load()` method (which latter its syntax is a bit 'more verbose)?
Thanks again